# How do I add elements above a UITableView that is animated down

Tags: iphone, uitableview, viewcontroller

Basically, I am trying to add a View above a UITableView programatically.  The code below, will animate the UITableView down 150 Pixels and I would like to add elements to the space that is created above.  But anytime I try to add something, like the Label in the code, it disappears.  It's a UITableViewController so I am thinking that might have something to do with it.

Help!

```
- (IBAction)chooseCity:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
if (frame.origin.y > 0) {
    frame.origin.y = 0;
} else {
    frame.origin.y += 150;        
}
[self.tableView setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];

UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -30, 200, 30)];
testLabel.text = @"Hello";
testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add UILabel at top of view, you can add it in tableview's tableHeaderView property,

Allocate UILabel and assign it to tableHeaderView, Even you can put this part in UIView animation, so it will animate according to your requirement.

Comment: After reading this I kinda got it to work, but what I am trying to do is mimic the Engadget app.  From the main screen of that app, if you click the arrow in the top right it slides down and shows all the engadget sites.  It's almost as if it's been placed in the App Delegate or something.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -30, 200, 30)];
testLabel.text = @"Hello";
testLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

tableView.tableHeaderView = testLabel;
[testLabel release];
//to add in footer tableView.tableFooterView = testLabel;
```

according to your condition you can set that to nil

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = testLabel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would implementing this in

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return someViewIWantInMyHeader;
    }

}
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {

         return someSize;
    }
}
```

not work for you?